# Get records via foreign key in another table in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I need to get all seats attached to a specific reservation.

I have these classes:

```
public class Seat
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string RowNumber { get; set; }
    public int SeatNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ReservationSeat
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ReservationId { get; set; }
    public Guid SeatId { get; set; }

    public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
    public Seat Seat { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried with this linq to entities statement but with no luck. It seems to return all the seats from the seats table.

```
public static List<Seat> GetSeatsForReservation(Guid reservationId)
{
    using (var db = new EntityContext())
    {
        return db.Seats.Where(s => db.ReservationSeat
                                     .Select(rs => rs.ReservationId)
                                     .Contains(reservationId)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
public static List<Seat> GetSeatsForReservation(Guid reservationId)
    {
        var db= new  EntityContext();
        return (from s in db.ReservationSeat
                where s.ReservationID==Guid
                select s.seat).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.. i got it to work and turned it in to this statement:

`return db.ReservationSeat.Where(rs => rs.ReservationId == reservationId).Select(rs => rs.Seat).ToList();`

Comment: I will be honest, I still don't get the "=>". So I end up using the long way all the time

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the `s` variable in your predicate.  You're basically asking the DB for any row where "any `Reservation` row in the DB matches the ID".  Since there's always one that matches, all rows will evaluate to `true` in that predicate.

It sounds like you're looking for something more like this:

```
.Where(s => s.Reservation.Id == reservationId)
```

Answer (score 0):

In EF Code-First ForeignKey can be applied to properties of an class and the default Code-First convention for ForeignKey relationship expects foreign key property name match with primary key property. Thus, you can create you model as bellow:

```
public class Seat
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string RowNumber { get; set; }

    public int SeatNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }
}

public class Reservation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Seat> Seats { get; set; }
}

public static List<Seat> GetSeatsForReservation(Guid reservationId)
{
  List<Seat> result = null;
 using (var db = new EntityContext())
  {
     result = db.Seats.Where(
            s => s.Reservations.Id == reservationId).ToList();
    }
   return result ;
 }`
```

Note: 1. this is many to many relationship, you can change it to 1 to many 
      2. navigation property must be declared as public, virtual